# I am working on salesforce shield encryption. How to retrieve whether the the field is encrypted in metadata?

Tags: salesforce, metadata

I have tried https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm ..but i'm not able to retrieve information about encrypted field in metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = CustomObject__c.customField__c.getDescribe();
system.debug(F);
```

Here you can see for example:

- isEncrypted
- getType (e.g. ENCRYPTEDSTRING)

Answer (score 0):

following code gives you the field result

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult describeFieldResult = CustomObject__c.customField__c.getDescribe();
```

Using the describeFieldResult field you can check your field if it is encrypted in metadata.